# In ASP.Net Zero, How to download an image without passing the auth token in the header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

We're adding uploading / downloading files to a web app built on top of ASP.Net Zero. How to implement the authorization on images in the download?

I found that the cookie contains `enc_auth_token` but seems it is not checked in the server and I am getting unauthorized if the auth token in the header is not passed.

Version Info: ASP.Net Core + Angular

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new controller that bypasses auth for images. Get image path and serve the image from your new controller. You can define a route for your images.

> You can disable authorization for a method/class by
>   adding AbpAllowAnonymous attribute to application services. Use the
>   AllowAnonymous attribute for MVC, Web API and ASP.NET Core
>   Controllers.

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization#suppress-authorization

Updated:
Check out the code that gets the image of user.

```
 [AbpMvcAuthorize]
    [DisableAuditing]
public class ProfileController : AbpController
    {

 public async Task<FileResult> GetProfilePicture()
        {

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserByIdAsync(AbpSession.GetUserId());

            if (user.ProfilePictureId == null)

            {

                return GetDefaultProfilePicture();

            }


            return await GetProfilePictureById(user.ProfilePictureId.Value);

}

        }
```

Comment: I don't want to bypass authentication, I want 1. Only authenticated users to see images, 2. Even if I passed the authentication, how can I get the session info (tenant ID, etc) ?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: In your updated answer, the controller won't allow requests without auth token. Please read my question again

Comment: Without auth token how will you authenticate request? And how can you define the session user?

Comment: Well, first I found in the cookie we have `enc_auth_token` value but not sure if we can use it. Second, I can find a way by intercepting the request and pass the token, but checking first if there's an out of the box solution since you're storing the token in the cookie anyway